# Fatal Exception : java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: GoogleApiClient parameter is required

Tags: java, android

I'm trying to create an Android Location API using Google Play Services.
But I keep on getting " java.lang.IllegalStateException: GoogleApiClient is required ".
Can anyone tell me what I am doing wrong?
Here's the code which I have been trying.

CODE:

```
package com.example.jamshi.locationapi;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.location.Location;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.google.android.gms.common.ConnectionResult;
import com.google.android.gms.common.GooglePlayServicesUtil;
import com.google.android.gms.common.api.GoogleApiClient;
import com.google.android.gms.common.api.GoogleApiClient.ConnectionCallbacks;
import com.google.android.gms.common.api.GoogleApiClient.OnConnectionFailedListener;
import com.google.android.gms.location.LocationListener;
import com.google.android.gms.location.LocationRequest;
import com.google.android.gms.location.LocationServices;

 public class MainActivity extends Activity implements ConnectionCallbacks,OnConnectionFailedListener {

    private static final String TAG = MainActivity.class.getSimpleName();
    private static final int PLAY_SERVICES_RESOLUTION_REQUEST = 1000;
    private Location mLastLocation;
    private GoogleApiClient mGoogleApiClient;


    private TextView tvLocation;
    private Button btnShowLocation,btnLocationUpdates;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        tvLocation = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tvLocation);
        btnShowLocation = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnShowLocation);
        btnLocationUpdates = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnLocationUpdates);

        boolean checkPlayServices = false;
        if(checkPlayServices){
            buildApiClient();
        }

        btnShowLocation.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                displayLocation();
            }
        });



    }

    private void displayLocation() {
         //buildApiClient();
        mLastLocation = LocationServices.FusedLocationApi.getLastLocation(mGoogleApiClient);

        if (mLastLocation != null) {
            double latitude = mLastLocation.getLatitude();
            double longitude = mLastLocation.getLongitude();
            tvLocation.setText(latitude + ", " + longitude);

        } else {

            tvLocation.setText("(Couldn't get the location. Make sure location is enabled on the device)");
        }
    }

    private boolean checkPlayServices(){
        int resultCode = GooglePlayServicesUtil.isGooglePlayServicesAvailable(this);
        if(resultCode != ConnectionResult.SUCCESS){
            if(GooglePlayServicesUtil.isUserRecoverableError(resultCode)){
                GooglePlayServicesUtil.getErrorDialog(resultCode,this,PLAY_SERVICES_RESOLUTION_REQUEST).show();
            }else{
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"This device is not supported",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                finish();
            }
            return false;
        }
        return true;
    }

    protected synchronized void buildApiClient() {
        if (mGoogleApiClient == null) {
            mGoogleApiClient = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(this)
                    .addConnectionCallbacks(this)
                    .addOnConnectionFailedListener(this)
                    .addApi(LocationServices.API).build();
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void onStart() {
        super.onStart();
        if (mGoogleApiClient != null) {
            mGoogleApiClient.connect();
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void onResume() {
        super.onResume();

        checkPlayServices();

    }






    /**
     * Google api callback methods
     */
    @Override
    public void onConnectionFailed(ConnectionResult result) {
        Log.i(TAG, "Connection failed: ConnectionResult.getErrorCode() = "
                + result.getErrorCode());
    }

    @Override
    public void onConnected(Bundle arg0) {

        // Once connected with google api, get the location
        displayLocation();

    }

    @Override
    public void onConnectionSuspended(int arg0) {
        mGoogleApiClient.connect();
    }


}
```

Answer (score 0):

Because mGoogleApiClient is null.

buildApiClient() method is never called also, probably you made a mistake in onCreate

```
 boolean checkPlayServices = false;
 if(checkPlayServices){
     buildApiClient();
 }
```

**Elaborated**

This checkPlayServices variable here false, so it does not call buildApiClient() method, as a result mGoogleApiClient is null.

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    ...
    boolean checkPlayServices = false;
    if(checkPlayServices){
        buildApiClient();
    }
}
```

connect method is not called, because  mGoogleApiClient is null

```
@Override
protected void onStart() {
    super.onStart();
    if (mGoogleApiClient != null) {
        mGoogleApiClient.connect();
    }
}
```

After the activity is created, and when you call displayLocation() method, it crashes due to mGoogleApiClient is null

```
private void displayLocation() {
     //buildApiClient();
    mLastLocation = LocationServices.FusedLocationApi.getLastLocation(mGoogleApiClient);
    ...
}
```

Comment: Can u please elaborate it??

Comment: I understood the mistake and I just removed " boolean checkPlayServices = false; " from code..................................but compile time error occurs stating that " Cannot resolve symbol " checkPlayServices "  ".......................... can u please correct the mistake..................................

Comment: Oh no no, the problem is not checkPlayServices variable itself. 
Just check here https://guides.codepath.com/android/Retrieving-Location-with-LocationServices-API

Comment: This link refers you initializing the mGoogleApiClient in onCreate for example. 
In your code, just allow the buildApiClient() method is being called. Check my answer again, if you read the link properly.